# Different given names in Chinese and English

Tags: names

Chinese business persons often have a different given name in English than in Chinese. For example, Tencent founder [Ma Huateng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma_Huateng) is internationally known as Pony Ma while his co-founder [Zhang Zhidong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Zhang) is known as Tony Zhang. I have seen the same phenomenon in actors from Hong Kong (e.g. [Jackie Chan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackie_Chan)).

Is there a system to (some of) these "translations"? Does a specific Chinese given name have a specific English corresponding given name? Or are they completely made up, and by whom?

Answer (score 3):

There's no system; English names can be chosen essentially randomly, and the reasoning (if any) behind the choice may not be obvious unless the person explicitly tells the backstory behind the name.

- Ma Huateng's (馬化騰) name *Pony* comes from the Chinese practice of [adding the prefix 小 in front of the family name to indicate informality or affection for young people as the addressee](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F#Definitions), which becomes 小馬 (**Xiǎo Mǎ**), as 馬 (**Mǎ**) is his last name. 小馬, as a Chinese word, [literally means *Pony*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%B0%8F%E9%A6%AC).
- Zhang Zhidong's (張志東) name *Tony* doesn't seem to be explicitly explained, although one can infer that it might have been chosen for one or more of the following reasons:

  - *Tony* sounds similar to 東 (**Dōng**), the last character of his first name;
  - *Tony* was chosen to rhyme with *Pony*.
- Jackie Chan's name came about because he worked under a construction worker named *Jack*; he was known as *Little Jack* due to his apprentice role, which later changed to *Jackie*.